# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not showing data in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I've a Fragment where I'm trying to show the ListView using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter which comes in     `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.2'`.

My Fragment code goes like this :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView services_list;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AllServices");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        services_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.services_list);
        services_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        services_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Services, ServiceViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Services, ServiceViewHolder>(
                Services.class,
                R.layout.service_row,
                ServiceViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ServiceViewHolder viewHolder, Services model, final int position) {

                viewHolder.setServiceName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setServicePrice(model.getPrice());
                viewHolder.setImage(getContext(), model.getImageUrl());

                viewHolder.service_name_textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked on Service Name "+(position+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.service_price_text_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked on Service Price "+(position+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.service_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked on Service Image "+(position+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        };

        services_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }

    public static class ServiceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        View mView;
        TextView service_name_textview;
        TextView service_price_text_view;
        ImageView service_image;

        public ServiceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setServiceName(String title)
        {
            service_name_textview = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.service_name_textview);
            service_name_textview.setText(title);
        }

        public void setServicePrice(String desc)
        {
            service_price_text_view = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.service_price_text_view);
            service_price_text_view.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setImage(final Context ctx, final String image)
        {
            service_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.service_image);

            //Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);

            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(service_image, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(service_image);
                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

My Services.java code goes like this :

```
public class Services {

    private String Name;
    private String ImageUrl;
    private String Price;

    public Services() {
    }

    public Services(String name, String imageUrl, String price) {
        Name = name;
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        Price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return ImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

There are 21 rows to be displayed into the RecyclerView.

NOTE : once when I installed app for the first time then the data get loaded into the recyclerview (and in the logcat there was images link from where the images were getting downloaded) but after that the data never loaded into the app.

I'm really trying hard to get it sorted but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem occurred me. Simply remove the `service_list.setHasFixedSize(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is an issue in sizing of `Recycleview`
I also had the same problem that I fixed it with setting

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

just set `height` and `width` to `match_parent`